# "Either of which" - meaning

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Stuck with a task in a LOGIC TESTS book. What "either of which" should mean?

[task about doors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oyTD.jpg)

If meaning of "either of which" is exclusive OR then solution is straightforward: B bears a true sign and all is clear.

I, though, incline to understand context much broader: from "none of the doors" to "both doors" can be wired. In this case task becomes more tedious to solve as one needs to write down boolean expressions for A and B signs and run them against two scenarios.

Part of the confusion is caused by the first part of the text where authors used "either of which..." and later in the paragraph they specifically used "one of the signs..."

Comment: IMO, means "exactly one of them".

Comment: Please try to make your questions self-contained: it would be easy for you to type the question in the link into your question. Apart from that I disagree with your analysis and Mauro's opinion. The statement that one of the signs is true immediately implies that it is irrelevant how you read "either of which".

Comment: @RobArthan, yes, you are correct. Thank you.